# rails model unit test trying to hit database throws nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

Any suggestions on how to resolve this test error. The database has records which I try to fetch during test and run the test against.  I am using minitest 5.3.3, rails 4.1.1 app and ruby 2.0.0p247

The test output and error thrown:

```
 Finished in 0.017919s, 167.4200 runs/s, 55.8067    assertions/s.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  1)       Error:                                                                                                                                                                                     
   Ff::BendRateTest#test_class_method:                                                                                                                                                        
   NoMethodError: undefined method `rate' for nil:NilClass
```

Which is caused by this line that uses activerecord scopes to query the database. So I try to get the record nd then get the value of the rate from the fetched record:

```
d = Ff::BendRate.by_counter(letter_b)
```

The test class:

```
 module Ff
   class BendRateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

     def test_class_method
       m = Ff::BendRate.convert('2014-05-06', 10, 'us', 'gb')
       assert_equal 5, m
     end  
    end
  end
```

The model is shown below:

```
 module Ff
  class BendRate < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :by_counter, -> (letter) {where(letter: letter) } 

    def self.convert(date, amount, letter_a, letter_b)
     Bender.new(date, letter_a, letter_b).converter(amount)
    end  

  end
 end
```

The Bender class that we instantiate in the model above:

```
  class Bender

   def initialize(date = Date.today, letter_a, letter_b)
     @letter_a =  letter_a
     @letter_b = letter_b
     @date = date
   end

   def attempter
    baseup(@letter_a, @date)
    counterup(@letter_b, @date)
   end

   def converter(amount = 10)
    @rate = attempter
    (@rate * amount.to_f).round(4)
   end

   private

   def counterup(letter_b, date)
     d = Ff::BendRate.by_counter(letter_b) 
     e = d.first
     @counteracting = e.rate.to_f
     @counter_up_rate = (@counteracting / @baserater).round(4)
   end

   def baseup (leter_a, date)
    a = Ff::BendRate.by_counter(letter_a) 
    b = a.first
    @baserater = b.rate.to_f
    @base_to_base = ( @baserater / @baserater).round(4)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test do not show, why it should return `5` items, you do not have any code which insert manually or by fixtures. You should explicitly show in your tests that you added all needed records, and then check that your methods working correctly with that data.

Elsewhere my steps which I'd use to find the problem:

1. Write test for `BendRate#converter` - it should fail with the same error
2. Write test for `Bender#attempter` - it should fail with the same error, too
3. Write tests for scope `BendRate.by_counter` for two cases `letter_a` and `letter_b` - it will fail because you have not `setup` data

or cheater way:

```
 def test_class_method
   p Ff::BendRate.all
   m = Ff::BendRate.convert('2014-05-06', 10, 'us', 'gb')
   assert_equal 5, m
 end
```

Comment: thanks. **5** is what I get in the rails console when I call **Ff::BendRate.convert('2014-05-06', 10, 'us', 'gb')**, hence I expected it to return thesame value when thesame command is called from the test with the intention of hitting the database. With the fixtures have suggested, I won't be hitting the database and I want to hit the db. what is your view on that?

Comment: @brg, maybe I have misunderstanding, elsewhere:

* have you run `rails console` in `test` ENV?
* I'm not clea understand, what does "hit" mean in this context. If hit is accessing DB by real request, then fixtures will use real database: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. No I didn't run **rails console** in **test** ENV?. I only ran **rails console** in development to see what value is returned when I run the command ** Ff::BendRate.convert('2014-05-06', 10, 'us', 'gb')**. Yes, by hit I meant accessing BD by real request to fetch record in this case using the scope defined in the model. When I run ** Ff::BendRate.convert('2014-05-06', 10, 'us', 'gb')**, it calls another method that fetches record from the **db** using activerecord scopes. I will read that link now. thanks